# How can I do to limit a RewriteRule only for the current directory with .htaccess?

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's assume that we're are talking about `website.com` and in the root directory there is a folder called `tags`.

This directory helps me to have "dynamic urls", for example: `website.com/tags/my-dinamic-url` or `website.com/tags/another-example`.

To do this, after an entire day of search :) I discovered that can be made by using .htaccess and at the moment it looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?t=$1 [QSA]
```

In my small point of view it is fantastic, can be funny for someone but after hours and hours of search on stackoverflow.com I finally understand something about the .htaccess file and about RewriteRule.

**The problem is:** Now, this RewriteRule continues endlessly because instead of just limit to `website.com/tags/my-dinamic-url` it continues also if I try something like `website.com/tags/my-dinamic-url/continue/another-continue/endlessly`.

How can I do to stop it? I need that if someone add a slash the page needs to return the 404 error.

So `website.com/tags/my-dinamic-url` need to work but `website.com/tags/my-dinamic-url/` or `website.com/tags/my-dinamic-url/something` needs to return the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

The endless redirect can be prevented by checking if the uri starting with `/tags`. Assume the rewrite rule only apply when the uri is one level deep:

```
# pass if the uri not starting with /tags/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tags/ [NC]

# redirect, ([^/]+) matches any characters, except / character (slash)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /tags/$1 [R,QSA,L]
```